# Can I access Meteor's minification machinery at runtime?

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app that makes an external service call for generating PDFs. The external service accepts a blob of HTML/CSS and gives back a URL to the generated PDF.

I'd like to minify before making the POST. Meteor clearly has significant minification machinery within the framework somewhere (eg. `meteor build`).

Is there an existing API to this that is accessible at runtime? I'd prefer something like `var minifiedString = Blaze.minify("<html>...</html>", {my: "options"});` over adopting another npm dependency, but I'm not sure if or where this would be exposed to the running server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. First of all, Meteor doesn't minify HTML–even during the build process–because it compiles the markup to JavaScript (in case you are using Blaze). And the minifier plugins for JavaScript and CSS are build plugins that are not bundled with your application.

Using packages like [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier) and [clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css) shouldn't be a problem if you only use them on the server because they are not packaged with the client-side part of your app.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I forgot it was JS functions all the way down.